# JSHint Eclipse Plugin Predefined Variables Throwing Not Defined Warning

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jshint

After a lot of troubleshooting, I've simplified my test case to just this... I'm using only a brand new download of Eclipse Juno and the JSHint plugin. Then I start a new project.  The checkbox 'Enable project specific settings' within JSHint's preferences pane is checked. I've left Predefined globals empty.  Within JSHint options I've put 'trailing: true'.  The only file in my project is foo.js.  It has one line:

```
foo.bar();
```

This line has a trailing whitespace. When saved, the trailing whitespaces throws a warning, but the undefined foo does not.  When I correct the trailing whitespace, foo is undefined still does not appear.  I've tried a number of other combinations of undefined variables to no avail. I've even tried adding some non-sense to the predefined variables to see if that does anything. Nope.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "undef: true" to your options to get the undefined warning.